# How to load javascript globally on a web-based Rhomobile application

Tags: rhomobile

We are looking at transferring our web-based app from Naurtech CETerm to Rhomobile. We can change javascript functions/meta tags to use the methods of Rhomobile instead of CETerm, but due to the poor hardware performance of our devices the slow down caused by the overhead of loading jQuery and other files is significant. (Prior to this we had no requirement for jQuery, although it would have been nice to have it). We also now need the rhoapi javascript which is significant.

Is there a way to include these "framework" javascript files in the Rhomobile container app and have them available to all pages loaded without them needing to be re-parsed on each page load?

It is currently a web based app loaded using something like the following in our `rhoconfig.txt` file as opposed to a local file:

`start_path = 'http://xxxxxx.co.uk/login.php'`

My current understanding is that this means the `app/layout.erb` file cannot be used to solve this problem?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

More than RhoMobile Suite (and it's RhoElements enterprise device framework) you can take a look at [Zebra Technologies' Enterprise Browser](http://zebra.com/enterprisebrowser) that is intended to be used as a stand-alone industrial browser, targeting Windows Mobile/Windows CE and Android devices manufactured by Motorola Solutions (now Zebra Technologies).

On "not too old" Windows CE/ Windows Mobile devices Zebra's Enterprise Browser uses a webkit derived HTML5 capable renderer engine so, to answer your question, you can use [HTML5 application cache](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Using_the_application_cache) to download the JavaScript libraries only if there's an update, in this way you can remove any network delay.

I've seen some project using giant JavaScript files (well above 1MB compressed) on old WinCE 6.0 devices, the startup time is clearly the biggest problem, with the risk to look at a white page for 5-7s. This can be alleviated with an async loader and a splash screen. It's not going to make your page faster, but the user will know what is going on.

You can find more information about Enterprise Browser on Zebra Technologies developer website, the Launchpad, inside [Enterprise Browser area](https://developer.motorolasolutions.com/community/technologies/enterprisebrowser).

If you build your [custom RhoMobile web-app container](http://docs.rhomobile.com/en/5.2.2/guide/webcontainer) with the idea to use in server pages, local resources, you can hit some issues around [cross-site scripting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting) prevention policies.